# Patch method in mantle REST API, but not supported by Tomcat

Tags: moqui

In mantle REST API, partial updates are done with PATCH method. however tomcat does not support PATCH method yet.

My question is how the PATCH method is handled in default deployment (and most of deployment is done with Tomcat)?

Comment: Have you tried this with more recent code? I'll admit I need to do more extensive testing with some of this, and on different app servers, but the MoquiServlet now overrides the service() method instead of the doGet(), doPut(), etc methods. In the Java Servlet API there is no doPatch() method, so this seems to be the only way to get it. If there are issues with this we may have to change patch to not allowed and just use put.

Comment: I tried this with the following and it made it through just fine (with the latest code... does need the MoquiServlet update!):

Comment: curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u john.doe:moqui -d '{ "firstName":"Not John" }' http://localhost:8080/rest/s1/mantle/parties/EX_JOHN_DOE/user

Comment: Great! just quick run it with c464d2f, the patch works fine.